# Client IP address in ASP.NET (.asmx) webservices

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asmx

I am using ASP.NET (.asmx) web services with Silverlight. Since there is no way to find the client IP address in Silverlight, I had to log this on the service end.
These are some methods I have tried:

```
Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_HOST")
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
Request.UserHostAddress()
Request.UserHostName()
string strHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
string clientIPAddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses(strHostName).GetValue(0).ToString();
```

All the above methods work fine on my local system, but when I publish my service on a production server, it starts giving errors,

> Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. StackTrace:
>
> at System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIWorkerRequestInProc.GetAdditionalServerVar(Int32 index)
>
> at System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIWorkerRequestInProc.GetServerVariable(String name)
>
> at System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIWorkerRequest.GetRemoteAddress()
>
> at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_UserHostAddress()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look using Reflector at the System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIWorkerRequestInProc.GetAdditionalServerVar code, that's what we see:

```
private string GetAdditionalServerVar(int index)
{
    if (this._additionalServerVars == null)
    {
        this.GetAdditionalServerVariables();
    }
    return this._additionalServerVars[index - 12];
}
```

I see two reasons why this could raise a NullReferenceException:

1) there is a multithreading issue on the _additionalServerVars member. I don't think this could happen because A) I don't see why there would be big load on your server during test, and B) the ISAPIWorkerRequestInProc instance is probably tied to a thread.

2) your server is not up to date and the code in production is not the same as the one I'm seeing on my machine.

So what I would do is check the server making sure it's up to date with the .NET Framework dlls.

Answer (score 5):

You should try to find out exactly where the `NullReferenceException` is coming from. Change your code to understand that certain things can return null. For instance, in

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]
```

`HttpContext.Current` could retrun null, or `.Request` could return null, or `.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]` could return null. Also, in

```
string clientIPAddress = System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(strHostName).GetValue(0).ToString();
```

the `GetHostAddresses(strHostName)` could return null, or the `.GetValue(0)` could return null.

If a method or property could return null, then you should check for null before dereferencing it. For instance,

```
IPAddress[] hostAddresses = System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(strHostName);
string clientIPAddress;
if (hostAddresses != null)
{
    object value = hostAddresses.GetValue(0);
    if (value != null)
    {
        clientIPAddress = value.ToString();
    }
}
```

P.S. I don't know why you'd use `GetValue(0)`. Use `hostAddresses[0]` instead.

Comment: NULL Reference Exception occurs when I try Request.UserHostAddress 
or HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]
I just cant find out any way to get the client IP in my asmx service. =(

Comment: @Zain: Like I said, check for null before you use any of these values. In fact, make sure to test `HttpContext.Current` to see if it's null before you try `HttpContext.Current.Request`.